# Firefox, move Web Console window?

Tags: windows-7, windows, firefox, user-interface

Using Windows 7, if you select `Position`, `Window` for the Firefox Web Console, it pops out as a window.

This window cannot be moved.

Any way to fix this?

Comment: What Firefox version are you using? I can move and resize that window just fine (Firefox 11, Windows 7).

Comment: @StevenPenny Which version of **Firefox**?

Comment: Firefox 11, Windows 7 64-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least since version 25, this has been resolved.